# How to make button unclickable if Ajax has not received a response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What I want to do is, when a user clicks a button and Ajax is waiting for a response, the button should be unclickable until Ajax receives the response. How can I do this?

script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#sendRestorePass').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = {};
        data.restoreEmail = $('#restoreEmail').val();
        data.mypass = $('#mypass').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "view/restorePass.php",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {

                if (Number(response) === 0) {
                    $("#dialog-confirm-restoreEmail-0").dialog("open");
                    $('#restoreEmail').val('');
                }
                if (Number(response) == 1) {
                    $("#dialog-confirm-restoreEmail-1").dialog("open");
                }
                if (Number(response) == 2) {
                    $("#dialog-confirm-restoreEmail-2").dialog("open");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: As a sidenote, the duplicate is somewhat wrong, you should be using `prop('disabled')` and not `attr('disabled')`, always `prop` with properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run your function set the button to disabled with:

```
.attr('disabled','disabled');
```

When the ajax completes, set:

```
.attr('disabled', false);
```